# PHP - combining videos

Tags: php, video, video-streaming

I'm trying to combine 3 videos with php , but I have no idea how to do that.

What I'm trying to do is keep an intro and outro in the web-server and whenever I upload a video it should automatically combine the 3 of them ( Intro + video + outro ). I don't know if this is possible but I hope you guys have the answer to this and thanks.

```
<?php

$video = get_video('video.mp4');
$intro = get_video('intro.mp4');
$outro = get_video('outro.mp4');

$final = comb_videos($intro,$video,$outro);

save_video($final,'final_video.mp4');

?>
```

What I'm looking for is the `get_video`, `comb_videos` and `save_video` functions.

Comment: Check this library https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg

Comment: where can i find the docs ?

Comment: What is the end result you are aiming for? How should the videos be combined? Should there be a final video, containing all three? If so, should they be played one after the other?

Comment: the result should be the 3 videos combined in order in 1 mp4 file ( one video ) [intro-video-outro]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're essentially looking for an PHP extension that deals with editing video.

No experience myself, but there is e.g.:
http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/

I'm pretty confident a deeper search will reveal more options.